# Access SSRS 2016 New Reporting Portal

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have been trying out the SQL Server CTP 3.1 for a while. For a couple a weeks ago Microsoft released CTP 3.2 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2015/12/17/introducing-mobile-reports-and-a-brand-new-web-portal.aspx)  which should include the new Reporting Portal and the possibility to use the new Mobile Reports feature.

I have successfully upgraded my CTP 3.1 installation to 3.2. For some reason I cannot see/access the link to "Preview the new Reporting Services"

Microsoft indicated that the link to the preview of the new portal should be found in the upper left hand corner of the Reporting Portal. But I there is nothing visual to me.

SSRS Reporting Portal

[image]

Has anyone tried it out and successfully launched the preview of the new portal? Am I missing some setting?

Comment: I have successfully launched the preview, but I didn't do anything in particular to make it work. Did you just do a vanilla install?

Comment: What happens if you change Reports in your URL to Reports_Preview?

Comment: Yes. A total vanilla installation on a new VM. Trying to replace "Reports" with "Reports_Preview" gives me "Webpage not found". This is really strange. I can see that I have the new functionality for example the Enable/Disable subscriptions. So bits and pieces of the new functions seems to be there. Maybe I'll try to reinstall completely instead of upgradin from CTP 3.1 -> CTP 3.2

Comment: I am also trying to get the new UI to work in CTP 3.1, and have the same issue.  Also the "Reports_Preview" version gives me a "Page not found" error.  If this is resolved in CTP 3.2 or otherwise, please post back.  Thanks!

Comment: As stated in my initial post: I have upgraded to CTP 3.2 and the new UI is not working. In CTP 3.1 I dont think the new UI is included, so that if probably not a problem. Try to upgrade to CTP 3.2 and see if you get the new UI working.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. By trigger an update of the Report Manager URL I succeeded to get the preview portal working. It seemed like the preview URL was not created in the update, for some reason..

1. Navigate to Reporting Services Configuration Manager
2. Go to "Report Manager URL"
3. Change the virtual directory to someting else, click "Apply". Let the configuration manager to its thing. After complete, you can change back to the original value (Reports) again (and press Apply).

This should do the trick!

[Reporting Services Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGpc8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can go directly to the preview portal:

```
 http://<server>/reports_preview
```

as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170438.aspx)

Comment: I know that you can do that. But the problem was that the ReportServer didnt create the directories when upgrading to CTP 3.2. But as I stated in my previous message, I found a work around.